# JSON Feed as object

Tags: json, fullcalendar

From what I've seen it only accepts arrays. I'd like to add more data to the response and have the actual calendar data be a key in the json array.

Example

```
{
 'success': true,
 'error': null,
 'data':[]
}
```

So having the array instead of being the root object being for example 'data'.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you have to call your event feed via a custom function, so that you can receive the response from your server into the function, and then write code to only return the relevant part to fullCalendar. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: Having said that, I'd argue that in the specific example you've shown above it's unnecessary - the extra data you've suggested, "success" and "error" are things which can be represented by the HTTP status code returned by the server - if the request is successful, return 200 OK as the status, and then just include the relevant, requested data in the response. If something goes wrong, return a suitable HTTP status (e.g. 500 for a crash, 404 for Not Found, 403 for Forbidden etc) and optionally some extra text in the response to provide more detail. This would be a more RESTful structure.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah you're obviously right. The problem was showing an error message when an error occurs, but I agree that using 200 / 401 / ... instead of a success bool is way better. Thanks for the link!